# Specifying targetNamespace?

Tags: java, web-services

I am writing WSDL file. In WSDL file can I specify any URL to targetNamespace? Or should it be valid?
My project has two WSDLs. In both the WSDLs I gave same targetNamespace. will there be any issues? `Should targetNamespace be unique across WSDLs in the project`?

```
targetNamespace="http://wsdl.mycompany.com/service
```

Thsnks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can specify any URL (acctually any URI) as a valid target namespace since at that location mostly nothing will be found anyways. Like a sort of java packages you can see a namespace as a location ("context") in which your definition of elements, types and attributes will be integer (e.g. you for example have only one element 'Person' in your namespace unless the elements are otherwise different).

It is also possible to have as many WSDLs/ XMLs/ XSDs share the same namespace as you want.
Note in this case anything you define will be added to that namespace and must be integer within it because otherwise anyone that wants to generate stubs out of your WSDLs will get errors like "element xy is ambigious".

On the other hand you oftenly want to have certain aspects of your webservice in its own namespaces. 
So you maybe want a namespace http://www.myCompany.com/namespaces/comm to which all of your technical request-types (like 'SendBillToBackofficeRequest') will belong while you have a namespace http://www.myCompany.com/namespaces/baseTypes for any business objects like 'Bill', 'Account', 'Customer' and so on.

I recomend to read something about http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp to fully understand namespaces (it is acctually pretty easy yet most SWEs dont fully understand it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can specify any URL as Target Namespace. It is required to be a valid URL or URI (Not necessary deployed somewhere). Although it is a good practice to specify URL as namespaces. This help to make them unique and avoid conflicts.
Namespace are very similarly to java  packages, they help to avoid element name conflicts. You should go for different namespaces in both WSDL's

Comment: Actually it must be a valid URI and thatfore a valid URL. Its just like there has nothing to be hosted under said (valid) URI.